# Solving PDE in Python

Tags: partial-differential-equations, visualization, python

Does anyone know of a "nice" library for solving PDEs in Python that will compute a functional solution, u(x_1...x_n,t).

What I want is to be able to pass the PDE(eq), BCs, and/or IVPs and get back u. So like this...

```
u(x_1...x_n,t)='pde.solver'(eq,bc,ivp)
```

I have both Mathematica and MATLAB, I just want to use this for visualization purposes. I'm planning on passing my results through Blender and visualizing them there.

Comment: Have a look at https://fenicsproject.org

Comment: See the [Dedalus project](https://dedalus-project.org/).